# How to delete an index from the first list that is also in the second list

Tags: python-3.x

For example, I have 2 lists:

```
list1 = [6,6,6,6,6,6,6]
list2 = [0,2,4]
```

If there are the same indexes in the `list1` and `list2`, I need to remove these indexes from the `list1`, because I should sum the unique indexes from the list1, for example:

```
a = [1,2,3,4,5]
b = [0,2,4]

x = [a.index(i) for i in a]
y = [b.index(j) for j in b]

for idx in y:
    if idx in x:
        x.remove(idx)
print(sum(x))

printed is >> 7
```

I tried this but did not work if there are the same values in `list1`

```
a = [6,6,6,6,6,6,6]
b = [0,2,4]

x = [a.index(i) for i in a]
y = [b.index(j) for j in b]

for idx in y:
    if idx in x:

        x.remove(idx)

printed is >> 0
```

Comment: Do you mean removing the numbers present in `list2` from `list1`, if they are present in `list1` ? Because indexes refer to the location of a value in a list, e.g. in [1,2,3], 1 is at index 0, 2 is at index 1 etc.. And removing the same indexes doesn't make sense, since all indexes will be same till the end of the smaller list of the two

Comment: and that's why I have asked how to do it, when I have 6,6,6,6 in list, every index is the same and can remove only first index.

Answer (score 0):

Indexes and values are different. There will never be the same index twice in one list. You get their index by their value, however index(value) function gives you the first index which matches your value. Have a look at:

```
a, b, x = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7], [1,2,3], 0
c, d = len(a), len(b)
if d < c:
    d, c = len(a), len(b)
for i in range(c, d):
    x += i
print(x)
```

Comment: try to have 6,6,6,6,6 in list and you will see if there is no the same indexes.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not very clear, so here are two answers:

If you want to sum the elements from the first list that do not appear in the second list, here is a way to do it:

```py
a = [1,2,3,4,5]
b = [0,2,4]

# We create a set in order to have O(1) operations to check if an element is in b
b_set = set(b) 

# We sum on the values of a that are not in b
res = sum(x for x in a if x not in b_set)

print(res)
>>> 9
```

If you want to sum the elements of the first list that do not have their rank/index in the second list, a way to do that could be:

```py
a = [1,2,3,4,5]
b = [0,2,4]

# We create a set in order to have O(1) operations to check if an element is in b
b_set = set(b) 

# We sum on the values of a that don't have their rank/index in b
res = sum(x for (i, x) in enumerate(a) if i not in b_set)

print(res)
>>> 6
```

Comment: I need it to do when the list have the same values like 6,6,6,6 and the other list have 1,2,3 or what you want.